# Inculir objeto completo en relationships JSON API

Tags: python, json, djangorestframework

Buen día.
Estoy relizando una API para usuarios, utilizo jango REST Framework JSON API, el problema que tengos es que JSON Api responde de la siguiente manera:

```
{
"data": {
    "type": "UserViewSet",
    "id": "3",
    "attributes": {
        "password": "b'$2b$12$KANG.sypvTisDtEoT66opu4FpWhm.fs4ahf4RXzmluxCDl3D3f52m'",            
        "username": "test9099",            
        "email": "test9009@gmail.com",
        "name": "test2",
        "last_name": "test2_test1",
        ...
    },
    "relationships": {
        "country": {
            "data": {
                "type": "Country",
                "id": "2"
            }
        },
        "state": {
            "data": {
                "type": "State",
                "id": "1"
            }
        },
        "city": {
            "data": {
                "type": "City",
                "id": "2"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Y lo que necesito es esto:

```
    {
"data": {
    "type": "UserViewSet",
    "id": "3",
    "attributes": {
        "password": "b'$2b$12$KANG.sypvTisDtEoT66opu4FpWhm.fs4ahf4RXzmluxCDl3D3f52m'",            
        "username": "test9099",            
        "email": "test9009@gmail.com",
        "name": "test2",
        "last_name": "test2_test1",
        ...
    },
    "relationships": {
        "country": {
            "data": {
                "type": "Country",
                "id": "2"
                "name": "Guatemala" 
            }
        },
        "state": {
            "data": {
                "type": "State",
                "id": "1"
                "name": "Guatemala"
                "code": "09001"
            }
        },
        "city": {
            "data": {
                "type": "City",
                "id": "2"
                "name": "GUATEMALA"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

No se, si en "data" de las "relationships" se pueda agregar mas datos, los atributos de toda la relación.

codigo:

settings.py agregue esto:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
'PAGE_SIZE': 10,
'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'rest_framework_json_api.exceptions.exception_handler',
'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS':
    'rest_framework_json_api.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework_json_api.parsers.JSONParser',
    'rest_framework.parsers.FormParser',
    'rest_framework.parsers.MultiPartParser'
),
'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework_json_api.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer'
),
'DEFAULT_METADATA_CLASS': 'rest_framework_json_api.metadata.JSONAPIMetadata',
```

}

models.py

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    country_code = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class State(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    state = models.ForeignKey(State, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=12)    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=45)        
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=45)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    state = models.ForeignKey(State, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
```

serialize.py

```
class CountrySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Country
        fields = ('__all__')

class StateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = State
        fields = ('__all__')

class CitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = City
        fields = ('__all__')

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('__all__')
```

Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes añadir información de las relaciones dentro de tu serializer referenciando los fields añadiendo el nombre de la variable ForeignKey, 2 guiones bajos "__", nombre campo del modelo.

Ejemplo:

```
class serializerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
          field = ('name','relationship__name')
```

El único problema que vas a tener es que vas a tener que añadir todos los campos que quieres mostrar.